# cannot view webpages in emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I was working on a webview which was not working. I then noticed that I cannot even view google or any other webpage using the emulators browser.

What could be the reason for this? Also do I need to setup the emulator to connect to the internet some how?

Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the internet permission in your manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but yes I have set it.

Comment: Didn't think I would need to set it for the emulator browser, just the application manifest. But using the browser within the emulator does not let me connect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that 3G displays on the emulator. If it does not, try restarting the emulator.